# Set image to shopify app using osiset/shopify package

Tags: laravel, shopify, shopify-app

I have created the Shopify app using osiset/shopify package. But I did not find any way to change the application icon or image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcm3U.jpg)

Comment: You need to update the APP icon into the partner account where the account is set up for APP. there is no option to add an APP icon.

Comment: Simply go to your shopify partner account, select your app there, click on the app settings above and change the icon under the "App icon" topic.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have successfully changed.